# Как прибавить к unixstamp-метке интервал времени?

Tags: mysql, unixtimestamp

у меня есть база, где прописана дата выполнения действия. Действие можно ставить на паузу. Время, в которое поставили на паузу тоже заносится в базу. Нужно чтобы время, которое действие стояло на паузе добавилось к времени выполнения. И все UPDATEом через MYSQL.

Короче говоря мне нужно вычислить каким-то образом число, которое при прибавлении к UNIX числу давало мне искомую дату.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста формат даты выполнения действия и паузы?

Comment: все даты в формате UNIX

Comment: А пауза в секундах? Или хранится дата начала и окончания паузы?

Comment: Вы, видимо не знаете, что unixtime в секундах? Вы можете вычислять разницу времени с помощью простейших арифметических действий.

Comment: пауза = текущее время;
время паузы = текущее время - пауза;
время выполнения = время выполнения + время паузы;
как-то так чтобы было)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас оба значения хранятся в базе данных, вам не обязательно пользоваться `UPDATE`, достаточно при выборке запросить сумму этих двух чисел, чтобы получит смещенную стартовую дату

```
SELECT
  id,
  start_at + pause AS start_at
FROM
  tbl
```

Если требуется все же обновить дату, это так же можно выполнить суммированием

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  start_at = start_at + pause,
  pause = 0
WHERE
  id = 34324
```

**UPDATE**

Если вы храните начало паузы, тогда для вычисления интервала паузы можно воспользоваться MySQL-функцией `TO_SECONDS()` (доступна начиная с MySQL 5.7), которая переводит дату в секунды.

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  start_at = start_at + TO_SECONDS(NOW()) - TO_SECONDS(pause_at),
  pause_at = 0
WHERE
  id = 34324
```

Или функцией `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  start_at = start_at + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pause_at, NOW()),
  pause_at = 0
WHERE
  id = 34324
```

Comment: я понимаю, как это в базу заносить
`mysql_query("UPDATE pending SET status = $st, timeToSend = timeToSend + $curTime, pauseTime = $pauseTime WHERE index = $index") or die(mysql_error());`
с SQL запросами все ясно, проблем нет.
дело в том, что записей в базе с одинаковом $index может быть до 1000, т.е. и у каждого из них разное время выполнения. т.е. нужно как-то прибавлять к времени выполнения то время, на которое было приостановлено выполнение

Comment: @АнтонБурак а откуда поступает $pauseTime? Это значение тоже хранится в базе данных или оно поступает откуда-то из вне?

Comment: $pauseTime зависит от статуса действия(на паузе или активен) если статус активен, то $pauseTime = time();, если нет, то $pauseTime = 0;

Comment: Просто пауза это обычно интервал времени с началом и концом, у вас получается только метка времени - как вычисляете продолжительность паузы? Просто многие действия можно выполнить в базе данных, например, вместо time() использовать MySQL-функцию NOW() - тогда будет проще составить универсальный запрос.

Comment: действие ожидает своего исполнения, исполнение назначено на определенную дату и время. действие можно приостановить(пауза). при нажатии паузы в базу заношу текущее время(действие перестает ожидать исполнения). после отмены паузы(перевода действия в дальнейшее ожидание исполнения) от текущего времени отнимаю время, в которое была нажата пауза(нахожу разницу для определения количества времени прибывания действия на паузе) и прибавляю это время к времени исполнения... алгоритм вроде как должен работать, в нем можно запутаться, но вроде все ок, а вот программно не получается ничего((

Comment: @АнтонБурак дополнил ответ

Comment: 1305 - FUNCTION warfox_don.TO_SECONDS does not exist

Comment: version()
5.1.73

Comment: @АнтонБурак тогда лучше воспользоваться функцией TIMESTAMPDIFF(). Поправил ответ.

Comment: `$res = mysql_query("UPDATE pending SET status = $st, timeToSend = timeToSend + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),pauseTime), pauseTime = NOW() WHERE index = $index") or die(mysql_error());`
выдает совсем не то...

Answer (score 0):

я сам себя запутал был. ошибка была в получении из базы UNIX времени, поэтому и все дальнейшие вычисления не давали результата.

            `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pending WHERE index = $index");
            while($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $sleepTime = time() - $result2['pauseTime']; 
                $curTime = $result2['timeToSend'] + $sleepTime; 
                $id = $result2['id'];
                $res = mysql_query("UPDATE pending SET status = $st,pauseTime = 0, 
                       timeToSend = $curTime WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
            }`

Comment: Антон а можно вас спросить ? Для каких целей поставлена эта задача ?

Comment: @LenovoID, менеджер программы. в нем хранятся определенные действия для программы запланированные на определенную дату и время. я делал приостановку для действия. т.е. действие ожидает своего времени, ставим его на паузу, если действие на паузе оно  выполнятся не будет даже в установленное время. Задача была в том, чтобы после снятия действия с паузы добавить к времени выполнения то время, которое оно простояло на паузе... не знаю поймете ли вы, старался объяснять как можно яснее, но легко запутаться)

Comment: Японо мать , это уже суперпродвинутый mysql , но мне интересно